# Generic interface problem

Tags: c#, interface, generics

So here is my problem:

I have the interface:

```
public interface ICell<Feature> 
where Feature: struct, IComparable<ICell<Feature>>
{
    List<ICell<Feature>> Window { get; set; }
    Feature              GenusFeature { get; set; }
    Double               VitalityRatio { get; set; }
    String               PopulationMarker { get; set; }
    Boolean              Captured { get; set; }
}
```

And wanted to implement `ISubstratum` interface in this way:

```
public interface ISubstratum<K,T> : IDisposable 
where K : IDisposable
where T : struct
{
    ICell<T> this[Int32 i, Int32 j] { get; set; }
}
```

But compiler says that:

`The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'Feature' in the generic type or method 'Colorizer.Core.ICell<Feature>'. There is no boxing conversion or type parameter conversion from 'T' to 'System.IComparable<Colorizer.Core.ICell<T>>'.`

In some possible `ISubstratum` implementation I planned to pass a Bitmap as K && ICell (extented pixel info) as T.

How to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you've got to have an extra constraint on T:

```
where T : struct, IComparable<ICell<T>>
```

then it should work fine. That's required to satisfy the same constraint on `Feature` in `ICell<Feature>`.

I would also suggest you rename the type parameter `Feature` to `TFeature` to make it more obviously a type parameter.

Comment: Good call on the renaming of Feature. That actually caught me at first when I was reading the code.

Comment: Thank you! Now this builds fine)

Answer (score 1):

Because your constraint on the `T` generic type parameter of your `ISubstratum` interface is not specific enough. It should be:

```
where T : struct, IComparable<ICell<Feature>>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to require T to implement `IComparable<ICell<T>>` as defined by the ICell type definition.

Answer (score 1):

Is it because your `T` in `ISubstratum<K,T>` is only limited to struct, whereas the `T` in `ICell<T>` is required to also be `IComparable<ICell<T>>` ? If you add that additiion where, does it work?

```
public interface ISubstratum<K,T> : IDisposable 
where K : IDisposable
where T : struct, IComparable<ICell<T>>
{
    ICell<T> this[Int32 i, Int32 j] { get; set; }
}
```

?

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface ISubstratum<K,T> : IDisposable 
where K : IDisposable
where T : struct, IComparable<ICell<Feature>>
{
    ICell<T> this[Int32 i, Int32 j] { get; set; }
}
```